# Webpack not finding imports with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack

Im new to webpack and trying to get it set up to begin learning it. Im using firebase as well if that is of any value.

Im getting an error saying:

> The requested module '/dist/bundle.js' does not provide an export named 'hello'

Now I understand what this is. Its saying that it cant find the export in the bundle.js that is compiled from the entry point.

But I have no idea what im doing wrong and I have tried everyhting... I will explain further for clarity.

My entry 'index.js' has a export in it that is:

```
export function hello() { console.log('Hello World!') };
```

It IS being compiled into the output bundle.js because when I search for 'hello' in the
obfuscated code there is evidence the function is in there

I am then importing the function like this in my `<script type='module'>` tag that my firebase code is within like so:

```
import { hello } from '/dist/bundle.js'
```

And then just invoking the function with: `hello();` - But the loading of the page doesnt even get that far It just trips on the import

Ive configured my entry, the output - Webpack IS bundling the code. But I have tried MULTIPLE configurations of webpack given to me from tutorials and Chat GPT but still keep running into this same issue.

This is the average of the configurations I have tried:

```
module.exports = {
mode: 'development',
watch: true,
entry: './src/index.js', // Entry file containing the functions to export
output: {
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
filename: 'bundle.js', // Output bundled file name
},
```

I dont get this, what am I missing? What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to output an ES module.

See the [Module Definition Systems](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#module-definition-systems) documentation, we need to set `output.library.type` to `'module'` and `experiments.outputModule` to `true`.

> Output ES Module. Make sure to enable `experiments.outputModule` beforehand.

E.g.

Directory structure:

```
$ tree -L 2 -I 'node_modules'
.
├── dist
│   ├── bundle.js
│   └── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js

2 directories, 6 files
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        library: {
            type: 'module',
        },
    },
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true,
    },
};
```

`src/index.js`:

```js
export function hello() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
}
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

asset bundle.js 2.9 KiB [compared for emit] [javascript module] (name: main)
runtime modules 670 bytes 3 modules
./src/index.js 58 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 67 ms
```

`dist/bundle.js`:

```js
var o = {
        d: (e, r) => {
            for (var l in r) o.o(r, l) && !o.o(e, l) && Object.defineProperty(e, l, { enumerable: !0, get: r[l] });
        },
        o: (o, e) => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, e),
    },
    e = {};
function r() {
    console.log('Hello World!');
}
o.d(e, { o: () => r });
var l = e.o;
export { l as hello };
```

Create the `index.html` file in the `./dist` folder and add a `<script type='module' />` tag.

`dist/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
            content="IE=edge"
        />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module">
            import { hello } from './bundle.js';
            hello();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Open the HTML in the browser and check the console

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer... This has corrected the problem. Much appreciated!